# How does libsodium generate a keypair

Tags: encryption, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

For [public key encryption](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption.html) and [diffie-hellman](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/advanced/scalar_multiplication.html) in libsodium, I typically make private keys simply by generating 32 random bytes with `randombytes_buf` and then derive the public key (when needed) using `crypto_scalarmult_base`.

Is there any benefit to using `crypto_box_keypair` to generate a keypair (other than syntax)? Or does this function basically do exactly that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the `crypto_box_keypair()` function does.

The benefits of this function are clarity, and guarantee that the secret key is properly generated.

Comment: Once the crypto_box_keypair() function returns a public and private key - they are returned as uint8 arrays -> how do I convert them to usable strings (to send in json)

sodium.to_string doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

[https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/public-key_signatures.html](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42437/how-to-generate-ed25519-public-key-from-private-key-using-libsodium)

for example:

```
    unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES]; //Variable declarations
    unsigned char sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES]; Variable declarations
    crypto_sign_keypair(pk, sk);

    NSData *privateKeyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sk length:crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    NSData *publicKeyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pk length:crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];

    NSLog(@"%@",privateKeyData);  // target publick key data and secret key data
    NSLog(@"%@",publicKeyData);  
    //Other 
    NSLog(@"%s\n\n=====\n\n\n%s",pk,sk); //(nullable const void *)bytes
    Byte *byte = (Byte *)[publicKeyData bytes];
    NSLog(@"%s",byte);
```